# can I limit log4net to eventview by size?

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging, log4net, event-log

My webApplication uses log4net that writes to event-viewr.

I want to limit its size to 1 GB.

is there any way to do this within the webcofig?
(as it can be limited to log file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but not by default. Existing [EventLogAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.EventLogAppenderMembers.html) does not support MaximumLogSize.

[Event Log API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbswcb15.aspx) does support size constraints ([EventLog.MaximumKilobytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.maximumkilobytes.aspx) and [EventLog.OverflowAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.overflowaction.aspx) ) so you can extend existing appender and provide this feature.

From the MSDN

> The MaximumKilobytes property represents the size limit of the event log file. When the event log reaches the size limit, the configured OverflowAction value determines whether new entries are discarded, or whether new entries overwrite older entries.

--

> The OverflowAction value that specifies the configured behavior for storing new entries when the event log reaches its maximum log size. The default is OverwriteOlder.